# How to use git when pair programming

Tags: git, git-svn

I am working on an Apache project. I am seeking advice on how best to use git to support our slightly unusual workflow. I'm familiar with the main git commands but inexperienced in using it on a group project.

On my team we usually pair-program and, for various reasons, swap which developer's machine we're working on several times per day.

The central source code repository is SVN but a read-only git mirror exists.

I'd like my partner and I to be able to frequently pull commits from each other's local repositories, and (less frequently) fetch updates from the server and commit to it.

It seems that this won't play nicely with "git svn", as stated on https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html:

"it is recommended that all git svn users clone, fetch and dcommit directly from the SVN server, and avoid all git clone/pull/merge/push operations between git repositories"

What's the best way to use git to support our workflow? For example, would it be easier if we clone from the read-only git repository instead of using git svn, and occasionally commit to the svn repo by applying patches to a separate 'git svn clone'-d repo?

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Did you consider using shared feature branches on the svn server?

Answer (score 3):

We use a master repo on github.com and then have four developers working off of local clones. We also subscribe to using [Git Flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) for ease in managing our branches (*development, master, hotfixes, releases, features, etc.*)

We would encourage you to read up on [A Successful Git Branching Model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), use a single remote repo as your ***gold standard*** (*which is really a meta-thought in git, there is no such thing as a master like SVN*). Do all your dev on non-master branches, only pulling from the single remote (*not pulling from each others local repos*).

There are certainly a wide variety of ways to leverage git in a development workflow. This is one that has worked very well for our team.

**So how that might look in your environment?**

You have an svn repository (*lets call it* `svn`), you have read only git mirror of that, lets call it `roRepo`. We would suggest cloning the `roRepo` to a third remote repo, lets call it `flowRepo`. Then '***git svn clone***' the `svn` repository to `svnRepo`.

`flowRepo` should be where you (*dev1*) and your partner (*dev2*), and anyone else (*devN*) clone from. Thus you would end up with `dev1Repo` and `dev2Repo`. These dev repos would never pull or push to each other, they only pull/push to `flowRepo`.

From there, we encourage you to embrace the gitFlow model, not because it provides any black magic, but because it provide some easy handles for learning/managing the development workflow in git (*things like working with a dev branch, using feature and hotfix branches, release branches, etc. They all just work with git-flow handling the more complex git commands behind the scene for you*).

You and your partner would then push/pull to `flowRep` regularly throughout the day. Most likely on the dev branch, but if you are sharing work on a feature branch you might push/pull there too on ocassion.

As you (*rarely, and typically only for release/hotfix*) hit the points where you need to push back into svn, create a patch (*you probably want a nice script to handle this for you so it isn't manual*) from `flowRepo` to be applied to `svnRepo` and ultimately get sync'd back to the `svn` repository.

Our team did this for about a year with success until we successfully moved off of SVN altogether and had a pure git SCM solution.

*Why not just clone the `svnRepo` and skip the `flowRepo` altogether?*

Basically because it is tied to SVN, and while branching and committing are cheap in GIT, they tend to be much more expensive in SVN.

When using ***git-svn***, it is best to:

- Minimize the number of branches you have to sync back to the svn repo
- Don't count on seeing merges between branches done in git published back in svn: they won't appear. Only commit made on the git branch(es) that you `` `dcommit `` to svn will be there.

Therein lies the issue, because [git-flow (a branching model)](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is great at creating branches for representing the application development life cycle (feature, hotfix, dev, release, etc.), which would be expensive to sync back to svn.

This is not to say it can't be done, but over time, we believe it has a lot of potential to ultimately be much more difficult to maintain.

Comment: You seem to have completely ignored the fact that their "gold standard" repo is an SVN repo -- and from the asker's post, that seems unlikely to change

Comment: That is incidental they use git-svn ... simply put a git repo in front of svn as the remote, then get all the benefits of of using git and only deal with the svn when when you have something on the remote/master you want pushed back into svn. Even then, SVN is not the "gold standard" in their git repos ... there is no "gold standard", all git repositories are cloned equal. ;-)

Comment: How would you fetch updates from the Apache repo (whether its svn server or its read only git repo)?

Comment: @PhilHarvey I updated my answer and filled it out a bit more to address the way I would architect it.

Comment: @Bubba thanks for the detailed answer. I'm not marking it as "answered" yet because I haven't verified that it works well. My concern is about what happens when updates propagate from the svn server. I am concerned that this will always involve a git rebase at some point, which amounts to rewriting history, thereby complicating attempts to merge changes between my colleague and me. I don't *know*that this will cause problems, but equally am not convinced that it won't.